Kivy RecycleView custom labels
I'm creating an app with five screens.

On four screens the user can save different kind of data (number, string, list) to an sqlite3 database.
The fifth screen is the "History Screen" where the user can fetch the desired number of last elements from the database.

DB structure:



ListName
Date
Result1
Result1




DataInput
15/06/2024
85
None


DataInput1
15/06/2024
1, 2, 3
10, 11


DataInput2
15/06/2024
Python
None



On the History Screen I use RecycleView. It works but I want to improve it a bit. Unfortunately I'm stuck.
RecycleView now:

What I want to achive: to create a custom label for DataInput, Date, Result1, Result2 (and maybe a divider between the list name and the last number)
What I've tried so far: create a custom viewclass. The problem here is that I don't know how to populate the custom labels and achive the same result as you see in the picture above but with custom labels. I found similar questions here on stackoverflow but I still can't figure it out how to solve it.
Viewclass example:
<CustomView@BoxLayout>:
    value_listname: ""
    value_date: ""
    value_result1: ""
    value_result2: ""

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: root.value_listname
            color: 1, 1, 0, 1
            font_size: "13sp"
        Label:
            text: root.value_date
            color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        Label:
            text: root.value_result1
        Label:
            text: root.value_result2
        
        #Divider after the last number

Example code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
import sqlite3
import random
import datetime

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<CustomView@BoxLayout>:
    value_listname: ""
    value_date: ""
    value_result1: ""
    value_result2: ""

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: root.value_listname
            color: 1, 1, 0, 1
            font_size: "13sp"
        Label:
            text: root.value_date
            color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        Label:
            text: root.value_result1
        Label:
            text: root.value_result2
        
        #Divider after the last element


<DataInputScreen>:
    number_1: number_1
    number_2: number_2
    result: result
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        TextInput:
            id: number_1
            
            hint_text: "from... (int)"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "50dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            
        TextInput:
            id: number_2
            
            hint_text: "...to (int)"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "50dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.5
            
        Label:
            id: result
            
            font_size: "50dp"
            
        Button:
            text: "Show the number and save it to DB"
            
            on_release:
                root.random_choice()
                
        Button:
            text: "Go to 'History' screen"
            
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "historyscreen"
                
                
<HistoryScreen>:
    record_text: record_text            
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        TextInput:
            id: record_text
            
            hint_text: "Show the last 'n' record(s)"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: "50dp"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2       
                        
        Button:
            text: "Show the records from DB"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            
            on_release:
                root.show_records()
               
        Button:
            text: "Back to 'DataInput' screen"
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "datainput"    
                
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.600
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.500, "center_y": 0.350}
            RecycleView:
                id: rv
                viewclass: "Label"
                #viewclass: "CustomView"
                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None, dp(30)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'                   
                
    """
                    )


class DataInputScreen(Screen):
    number_1 = ObjectProperty()
    number_2 = ObjectProperty()
    result = ObjectProperty()


    def random_choice(self):
        first_number = int(self.number_1.text)
        second_number = int(self.number_2.text)

        if first_number > second_number:
            first_number, second_number = second_number, first_number

        x = random.randint(first_number, second_number)

        self.result.text = str(x)

        conn = sqlite3.connect("results.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (:ListName, :Date, :Result1, :Result2)",
                  {
                      "ListName": "DataInput",
                      "Date": datetime.datetime.now(),
                      "Result1": self.result.text,
                      "Result2": None})
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


class HistoryScreen(Screen):
    record_text = ObjectProperty()
    data_items = ListProperty([])

    def show_records(self):
        self.data_items = ""

        conn = sqlite3.connect("results.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT Date, ListName, Result1, Result2 FROM numbers LIMIT ?", (self.record_text.text,))
        records = c.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        for record in filter(None, records):
            for col in filter(None, record):
                self.data_items.append(col)

        self.ids.rv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in self.data_items]

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        sm.add_widget(DataInputScreen(name="datainput"))
        sm.add_widget(HistoryScreen(name="historyscreen"))

        """Create Database"""
        conn = sqlite3.connect("results.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("""CREATE TABLE if not exists numbers(
        Date text,
        ListName text,       
        Result1 text,           
        Result2 text
        )
        """)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

        return sm

myApp().run()

Could you help me?

You are setting the data to a list of strings, but  it should be a list of dictionaries (See the documentation).
To accomplish this you can modify your show_records() method to create the required data. Something like this:
def show_records(self):
    self.data_items = ""
    
    # these are the keys required for your RecycleView data
    keys = ['value_listname', 'value_date', 'value_result1', 'value_result2']

    conn = sqlite3.connect("results.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT Date, ListName, Result1, Result2 FROM numbers LIMIT ?", (self.record_text.text,))
    records = c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    tmp_data = []
    for record in filter(None, records):
        record_data = {}
        col_num = 0
        for col in filter(None, record):
            # self.data_items.append(col)
            record_data[keys[col_num]] = col
            col_num += 1
        tmp_data.append(record_data)

    # self.ids.rv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in self.data_items]
    self.ids.rv.data = tmp_data

And a slightly modified <CustomView@BoxLayout>: rule:
<CustomView@BoxLayout>:
    value_listname: ""
    value_date: ""
    value_result1: ""
    value_result2: ""

    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    Label:
        text: root.value_listname
        color: 1, 1, 0, 1
        font_size: "13sp"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
    Label:
        text: root.value_date
        color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
    Label:
        text: root.value_result1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
    Label:
        text: root.value_result2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40

        #Divider after the last element
    Widget:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.width, 2


Hey, John! Thank you for your help (again)! ;)
